# How to call a native C function from Flutter?

Tags: c, flutter, dart, interop

I want to call 'hello_world' function from Flutter.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include "hello.h"
__attribute__((visibility("default"))) __attribute__((used))
int main()
{
    hello_world();
    return 0;
}
void hello_world()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

I have tried this way in my plugin.dart:

```
final DynamicLibrary helloLib = Platform.isAndroid
    ? DynamicLibrary.open("libhello.so")
    : DynamicLibrary.process();

final void Function() hello =
helloLib
    .lookup<NativeFunction<Void Function()>>("hello_world")
    .asFunction();
```

In my main.dart file I tried this way:

```
body: Center(
          child: Text('Running on: ${hello}'),
```

But it shows void instead of showing the result. How to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post code, not _pictures of code_.

Comment: Read this article [C interop using dart:ffi](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/c-interop)

Comment: Your C code appears to a program (has a `main()`).  I think you need a Dynamic Library.